# Implementing a AMP based web application

Tags: amp-html

I have few questions around how a AMP based web application can be implemented. This is actually a list of questions, could actually be basic, but I need answered to fully understand this. I had posted this on Twitter @amphtml but was asked to post my questions here.

So here are the questions that I have.

==> For most web application (publishing or e-commerce) we would have a lot of API calls that give a response and this JSON data is used to populate the templates and then displayed to the user. With a SPA using Backbone, Angualr, etc. we usually do all this from the client side.

==> For AMP, we need the pages to be static (? Is this understanding correct ?)

==> For an AMP application (publishing or e-commerce) should the AMP pages be generated on the server (say Node) and then rendered from the server when a user hits a URL? This way we can make multiple calls from Node itself and have templates populated on Node and then Node renders a fully baked AMP HTML (? which should act as if it is static ?) when it is rendered on client (browser).

==> If the above approach is wrong/incorrect/non-performant, should there be a batch process running after a certain time period everyday to create static HTML pages (Product pages or new article pages) and dump all these on the server and so when a page is requested, the page is just sent over?

---

How does SEO work in both of the above cases?
How does Google AMP cache work for these pages (again in both cases above)?

==> Is my understanding completely wrong? Is this not how all this is supposed to work???!?!?!!?!?

==> Is there a better approach for building AMP web applications?

Comment: you need to show what you've attempted in order to elicit a response. Having said that, you're gonna need to use an iframe for most of your work.

Comment: You could use amp-list to get freshest data from a cors json endpoint and then use a template to show them. Take a look at this sample https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/

Comment: My questions are not around what AMP component I should be using, it is around the architecture as a whole.